# Strange behavior Powershell-script in Sharepoint 2019

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I wrote a script that traverses all content databases and retrieves information about websites from each of them.

Total number of databases: 1200,
Number of websites: about 39000

The number of websites in the databases is uneven. There are databases with 100 websites, while others have 10-20-30, etc.

At the very beginning, if a database has fewer websites, the script traverses it super quickly (less than a second), but towards the end, it takes around 3-5 seconds for each database with the same number of websites.

Why does this happen? Is it due to caching? Or did I make a mistake somewhere in the algorithm?

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

Measure-Command {

  $databases = Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication 'https://...'
  $emptyDB = 0
  $fullDB = 0
  $totalSites = 0

  foreach ($database in $databases) {
    if ($database.Sites.Count -eq 0) {
      Write-Host 'Database ' $database.Name ' is empty' -ForegroundColor Red
      $emptyDB++
    }
    else {
      Write-Host 'Database ' $database.Name ' has ' $database.Sites.Count ' sites' -ForegroundColor Green
      $fullDB++
      $sites = $database.Sites
      $siteInfo = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
      foreach ($site in $sites) {
        if ($site.Url.Contains("sitemaster")) {
          Write-Host $site.Url "was excluded from export" -ForegroundColor Yellow    
        }
        else {
          $UserEmail = $site.Owner.Email
          $siteUrl = $site.Url
          if ($site.Owner.Email -ne '') {
            $siteOwner = $site.Owner.Email 
          }
          else {
            $siteOwner = $site.Owner.DisplayName
          }
          $siteUsage = [math]::round($site.Usage.Storage / 1GB, 3)
          $siteLastTimeUsage = $site.LastContentModifiedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
          $siteDatabases = $site.ContentDatabase.Name
          $siteQuota = [math]::round($site.Quota.StorageMaximumLevel / 1GB, 3)
          if ($siteQuota -ne 0) {
            $QuotaUsage = [math]::round($siteUsage / $siteQuota * 100, 2)
          }
          $webTitle = $site.RootWeb.Title
          if (($UserEmail -ne '') -and ($UserEmail -like '*ozon.ru')) {
            $ozon = Get-AdUser -Server "ozon" -Filter { userPrincipalName -like $UserEmail } -Properties employeeType, manager
            if ($ozon.manager -ne $null) {
              $manager = Get-AdUser -Server "ozon" -Filter { distinguishedName -like $ozon.manager }
              $manager = $manager.userPrincipalName
            }
          }
          # Конвертируем дату увольнения в формат YYYY-MM-DD для загрузки в БД
          if ($ozon.employeeType -like 'Fired*') {
            $UserStatus = $ozon.employeeType.split()[0]
            $FiredDate = [datetime]::parseexact($ozon.employeeType.split()[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
          }
          else {
            $UserStatus = $ozon.employeeType
          }

          $siteInfo.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
              WebTitle      = $webTitle
              SiteURL       = $siteUrl
              Owner         = $siteOwner
              LastTimeUsage = $siteLastTimeUsage
              DiskUsage     = $siteUsage
              Quota         = $siteQuota
              QuotaUsage    = $QuotaUsage
              Database      = $siteDatabases
              Ozon          = $ozon.Enabled
              UserStatus    = $UserStatus
              FireDate      = $FiredDate
              Manager       = $manager
            })
        }
      }
      $siteInfo | Export-Csv -Path "C:\SysOps\SharePointSites.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ';' -Append
      $siteInfo | Export-Excel -Path "C:\SysOps\SharePointSites.xlsx" -Append
      $UserStatus = ''
      $FiredDate = ''
      $manager = ''
      $ozon = ''
      $site.Dispose()
    }

    $totalSites = $totalSites + $database.Sites.Count
  }

  Write-Host 'Empty databases - ' $emptyDB -ForegroundColor Red
  Write-Host 'Databases with sites - ' $fullDB -ForegroundColor Green 
  Write-Host '---'
  Write-Host 'Total sites - ' $totalSites -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: `Measure-Command` only gives you a single measurement - how are you determining that it's fast at first and slow later?

Comment: In the script, there is a line `Write-Host 'Database ' $database.Name ' has ' $database.Sites.Count ' sites' -ForegroundColor Green` for each database. And it can be seen that they appear at different speeds, initially very quickly, but the further, the slower. In addition, the data in the CSV files are dropping at different speeds.